# Shimano Acera Shifters - How to remove gear cable

Tags: shifter, cable

I need to change the front derailleur gear cable on my bike. I've removed the cable from the derailleur itself, and now need to detach it from the shifter on the handlebars.

On my previous bike, which also had Shimano parts (I think Tourney), when I had to do this I just unscrewed two screws on the top side of the shifter, the cover easily came off, and I could then access the cable.

On these Acera shifters, there are also two screws at the top, but after unscrewing them the cover won't pull off. I've tried this on both shifters with the same result. It seems I need to unscrew or do something else, but I'm not exactly sure what it is.

Rather than try to yank off the cover and end up damaging something, I thought I'd ask here if anyone knows how to correctly remove the covers on these shifters.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4):

On the outside of the shifter (where the levers are) there should be a single screw. Put the deraileur in the first gear (the gear with the least tension) and remove the screw. Then simply push the cable out.

Comment: Remember to cut off the cable end cap

Comment: +1, though you're pulling the cable out rather than pushing it.

Comment: @Batman - push and pull! Push till the cable stop comes out, pull the rest of the way.